# Why open strings must all end on same D brane?

Tags: string-theory, branes, compactification

Consider 10-d open string theory with a D9 brane (i.e. an open string), and $X^9$ compactified on a circle. T-dualising, we find a D8 brane. Why is it that the endpoints of all open strings in this dual theory must end on the same hyperplane? (ignoring Wilson lines).

Polchinski seems to give the reason that

> For two different open strings, consider the connected worldsheet that results from graviton exchange between them. One can carry out the above argument* on a path connecting any two endpoints, so all endpoints of all string lie on the same hyperplane.

*=where the argument was that integrating gives $X'^9(\pi)-X'^9(0)=-2\pi l R'$, where $X'^9(z,\bar {z})+X^9(z)-X^9(\bar{z})$ is the dualised coordinate and $R'$ the dual radius.

However, the sentence above is a bit cryptic for me. I guess by "the connected worldsheet that results from graviton exchange between them" he is referring to the surface formed by two different open strings coming in, merging, and then separating again (at tree level at least), i.e. topologically a disk with four punctures at the boundary? But even if so, I am unsure what this means in the context of D-branes. For instance, what if the significance of having chosen graviton exchange? Why not tachyons for instance?